# Review audit failed for flagging as duplicate

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/18737550) as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891331/find-non-ascii-characters-in-varchar-columns-using-sql-server) and got an automatic message that the audit failed. Aside from being a duplicate, the flagged post does not even show an attempt to research the question. This post is a poor choice for an audit, and I've been noticing more sketchy audits lately.

Could a feature be considered for the review queues in which an automated audit like this one could be marked as too ambiguous so that it stops coming up in the queue? The audits should be more clear-cut than this one.

Comment: As far as I know there is no dedicated place (or automatic process) to dispute/challenge bad review audits. If you were review banned due to such an audit, then you could flag the question and explain the situation in a custom moderator flag (like explained here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276155/how-do-i-challenge-an-audit-failure) or create a meta post, like you did here.

Comment: If you think it's a duplicate, vote to close it as a duplicate.   If you think it's poorly researched downvote it.  After having done that you'll have made the post ineligible as an audit.

Comment: @Servy - The user only has 745 rep, they can't vote to close. And they *did* say they flagged as a duplicate, which is as much as they could do.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas They tried to flag for closure, they failed the audit before it completed.  They'd need to flag it after the audit message for it to go through.  The post currently has no flags for a duplicate (you can go to the post to see for yourself), so we know that they didn't actually cast such a flag, even if they intended to, hence why I told them they still need to do it.

Comment: Wouldn't know, I can't see flags. :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I almost want to close the *older* one as being a duplicate of the *new one* because the answers are better. Or at least simpler. I don't have enough domain knowledge to tell if they actually work.

Comment: @gnat Didn’t find that post but yeah it’s pretty much the same question as mine. But I think the answer here is much more thorough.

Comment: Just had that same problem with review/audit question https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25005199 for which I found a duplicate, not knowing before the "You didn't pass" that it was an audit... So it still happens in 2020!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have only just started with review tasks, but I have read a lot of Meta questions about failed review audits. From what I have gathered, this is the situation (subject to correction by the community, of course):

The audit mechanism is completely automated. The question you tried to flag is upvoted, with 2 upvoted answers, with one of them accepted. As far as the automated audit process is concerned, this post has solid chops on Stack Overflow. The community has decided that the question and its answers are good quality.

When you hit the "Unsalvageable" button, the automated audit process basically responded with "Are you out of your mind?"

If you still think a question like this should be flagged/closed, you should do it outside of the review process. Just skip it in review, and go back to it to flag it or vote to close. Because even if you're correct, the audit will disagree with you based on the votes.

Comment: Well put. I’m still wondering if the audit system can be improved so situations like this don’t occur quite so often. But I gather that would be opening another can of worms.

Comment: @peacetype I don't think it happens that often to be honest. There's a few posts here a week about this but considering how many audits are being done daily I'm not sure it's a big problem.